# response.send (from node.js / restify app) by default serializes integer into 32-bit low/high parts?

Tags: javascript, node.js, restify

I am using node 6.x (npm 3.x) with restify (latest).  If a javascript object contains a property set to an integer, by default it looks like restify.send() will serialize that integer into "low" and "high" parts -- presumably representing the low/high 32-bit components of a 64-bit integer.

How can I turn off this default behavior, so that integers are not encoded into low and high parts?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce this behaviour when using [`integer`](https://github.com/JoshuaWise/integer), is that what you're using to represent integer values that may exceed JavaScript's [`Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER)?

If so, then you need to convert those `integer` instances to a proper JS number, otherwise they can't be represented as numerical value in JSON:

```
Number(obj.intProperty) // or: obj.intProperty.toNumber()
```

**HOWEVER**: I assume there's a reason for you using `integer`. If the number represented by `obj.intProperty` is too big to be represented as a plain JS `Number`, converting it may yield invalid results (that's why the JSON-representation of an `integer` is an object consisting of two 32-bit values).

**EDIT**: turns out that the issue was caused by the Neo4J driver's representation of 64-bit integers, as documented here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/neo4j-driver#a-note-on-numbers-and-the-integer-type

Comment: So, I am using the bolt / javascript driver to get records from a neo4j graph database.  I am guessing the bolt / javascript driver is serving integer values as type "integer" -- triggering the low / high behavior.  I will dig further, but it sure seems overkill to encode a number like "5" into low / high parts.

Comment: @KodeCharlie It looks like it might be the Neo4J driver that's doing this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/neo4j-driver#a-note-on-numbers-and-the-integer-type

Comment: The link you provided which describes how neo4j treats integers accurately characterizes the behavior I am seeing.  I will fix my code accordingly.  Thanks.